# Dashing a function in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I dash specific lines in Tikz that are defined by functions? For example, how would I dash only the black line in the following diagram?

```
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\foreach \a/\Col in {0.5/green,1.2/red, 1/black}
{
\draw[\Col] plot[domain=0:4,variable=\x,samples=90] ({\x},{5.7*\x*(\a*\x^\a)/(1+\x^\a)^2});
}
\foreach \a/\Col in {3/cyan,0.02/magenta, 1/black}
{
\draw[\Col] plot[domain=0:4,variable=\x,samples=90] ({\x},{5.7*(\a*\x^2)/(1+\a*\x)^2});
}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw [dotted] (1,0) node[below]{$1$} -- (1,4);
\draw [dotted] (0,1.1) node[left]{$0.5$} -- (4,1.1);
\node at (3.6,-.2) {$v_i$};
\node at (-.2,3.5) [rotate=90] {$b_i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do exactly the same thing you did for the colors.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\foreach \a/\Col/\dashing in {0.5/green,1.2/red, 1/black/dashed}
{
\draw[\Col,\dashing] plot[domain=0:4,variable=\x,samples=90] ({\x},{5.7*\x*(\a*\x^\a)/(1+\x^\a)^2});
}
\foreach \a/\Col/\dashing in {3/cyan,0.02/magenta, 1/black/dashed}
{
\draw[\Col,\dashing] plot[domain=0:4,variable=\x,samples=90] ({\x},{5.7*(\a*\x^2)/(1+\a*\x)^2});
}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw [dotted] (1,0) node[below]{$1$} -- (1,4);
\draw [dotted] (0,1.1) node[left]{$0.5$} -- (4,1.1);
\node at (3.6,-.2) {$v_i$};
\node at (-.2,3.5) [rotate=90] {$b_i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're the best!

Answer (score 5):

The two functions for the black curves are identical for `\a` = 1.
One of `1/black` in the `\foreach` list can be removed. The other can be moved outside of `\foreach` to apply a different line style:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\foreach \a/\Col in {0.5/green,1.2/red}
{
  \draw[\Col] plot[domain=0:4,variable=\x,samples=90]
    ({\x},{5.7*\x*(\a*\x^\a)/(1+\x^\a)^2});
}
\foreach \a/\Col in {3/cyan,0.02/magenta}
{
  \draw[\Col] plot[domain=0:4,variable=\x,samples=90]
    ({\x},{5.7*(\a*\x^2)/(1+\a*\x)^2});
}
\draw[dashed] plot[domain=0:4,variable=\x,samples=90]
  ({\x},{5.7*(\x^2)/(1+\x)^2});
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw [dotted] (1,0) node[below]{$1$} -- (1,4);
\draw [dotted] (0,1.1) node[left]{$0.5$} -- (4,1.1);
\node at (3.6,-.2) {$v_i$};
\node at (-.2,3.5) [rotate=90] {$b_i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]